# Calculating the number of positive and negative runs in a vector

Tags: r

I need to calculate (in R) the number of positive and negative runs in a vector. For example, suppose I have a vector `x`:

```
x = c(-23 , -2 , 5 , 8, 9, 12, -2, -1, 3, 5, 7)
```

than the number of runs is four, since I have: {-23,-2}, {5,8,9,12}, {-2,-1} and {3,5,7}. So basically every time the series changes sign, it counts as +1 in the run count.

Comment: What is "a run"?  Saying "the number of Runs is 4 because [comma-delimited list of numbers]" is not a clear explanation.

Comment: I think the posted question is clear.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your vector is in `x`, then `length(rle(sign(x))$lengths)` will do.